# having difficulty in understanding the working of this part of code

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

```
# Sample Data
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'description': ['d1', 'd2', 'd3'], 
                   'specialties': ['a1 A1,b2 B2,c3 C3', 'd4 D4,e4 E4,f5 F5,f6 F6', 'g5,h6,i7']}, 
                  index=['name1', 'name2', 'name3'])
df2['specialties'] = [','.join(x) for x in df2['specialties'].map(lambda x: x.lower().replace(' ','').split(',')).values]
```

Above piece of code take values from 'specialties' column and convert them into lower and remove spaces between words. I do not understand how the above line of code is actually working and changing the values. can someone please explain this to me ?

that's the output I am getting after executing above code.

```
name1         a1a1,b2b2,c3c3
name2    d4d4,e4e4,f5f5,f6f6
name3               g5,h6,i7
Name: specialties, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To analyze what is going on you have to break into atleast two statements.

First run:

```
df2['specialties'].map(lambda x: x.lower().replace(' ','').split(',')).values
```

This takes every value in the 'specialties column and pass it to the map function which runs the following methods.   `lower`, `replace` and `split` on commas.  This is return a list of lower cased strings.

Now, using that returned list, you are then concatenating the list parts back together using list comprehension and join.

```
[','.join(x) for x in newlist]
```

And, recreating the column list passed with lowercased letters.